# Apache Beam Pipeline Write to Multiple Sinks

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I have a scenario where I need to do the following:

1. Read data from a File stored in GCS
2. Apply multiple Transformations to the data.
3. Persist the PCollection in Google Big Query.
4. When Step 3. succeeds, write the PCollection to a Kafka Topic.

My question is how can I achieve it in Apache Beam. My main requirement is that I can ONLY write to Kafka if INSERT into Big Query succeeds.

I found something similar : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-ingest-avro-dataflow-sample/blob/HEAD/BeamAvro/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/solutions/beamavro/AvroToBigQuery.java

where the data is being written to GCS and to BQ. But my requirement is to write to Kafka ONLY after write to BQ succeeds. Does anyone know if it is possible and how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [WriteResult](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteResult.html) produced by a `BigQueryIO.Write` transform. It produces PCollections of successful inserts, which you can then write to Kafka (with some type conversion). Here's the gist of it:

```
WriteResult writeResult = pcol.apply(
    "InsertIntoBigQuery",
    BigQueryIO.writeTableRows());
PCollection<MyType> myType = writeResult
    .getSuccessfulInserts()
    .apply(
        "ConvertFromTableRowToMyType",
        /* Transform goes here. */);
```

From there you just output the elements to Kafka and that way you should only have elements written to Kafka that were successfully written to BigQuery.

Comment: Is it possible to directly have the original data instead of converting from TableRow to the original type ?